# Purescript - Unable to build with drawing and signals libraries

Tags: bower, purescript

I'm trying to start a purescript project that uses the purescript [signal](https://github.com/bodil/purescript-signal) and [drawing](https://github.com/purescript-contrib/purescript-drawing) libraries. When I try to `bower install` with both of them as dependencies, bower's interactive prompt asks to resolve several dependency versions. I admittedly pick the versions somewhat arbitrarily since most of the issues are several layers of dependencies deep. Then when I `pulp build` a basic hello world piece of code that doesn't even use the dependencies, pulp gives around 40 errors depending on which versions I selected.

How do I resolve these dependency versions correctly? Sifting through forty errors and all of the dependencies for both projects doesn't seem feasible. Is there some non-arbitrary way of picking the versions that will resolve the conflicts? From the choices it gave me, it didn't seem like there was any clear resolution. Or are their dependencies too conflicting and you just can't use them together?

This may actually be more of an question about bower, but it may also be something about purescript and pulp that I am just unaware of. They both seem like libraries that should be able to work together, and I can't imagine that other people are having too much difficulty using two or more libraries in a single project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Purescript 0.10 has breaking changes](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/releases/tag/v0.10.1). If you have the latest compiler, it's likely that it's not compatible with some libraries. From what I see, signal lib is updated but the drawing is not. You can update the lib and use your own version. Or, send a PR, Phil and purescript community in general, is really fast on responding to pull requests.
Another temporary solution is to use the old compiler (0.9) and wait a couple months till everything is back to normal.

also see [0.10 migration guide](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/wiki/0.10-Migration-Guide).

Comment: Thank you very much! It turns out I was using purescript 0.9. Maybe that means I couldn't have built the version of purescript-signal that migrated to 0.10 anyways. However, I just used the version of purescript-signal before they put in the changes for 0.10 and the hello world project built like a charm. I haven't tried actually using the libraries in a project yet but it seems like the main problem was due to what your answer described so hopefully I won't encounter any other problems.

Comment: Oh, and I'll look into making a pull request. I'm still pretty new to purescript but if it turns out to be just needing to change some versions and maybe changing some type classes, then I'll give it a shot.